# how to add string in source in .po file in poedit

Tags: wordpress, po, mo

I have created a ne_NP.po file from pot file and saved it.
It creates a .mo file and .po file and when i try to add a source text of ne_NP.po  file, it didnot let me to edit the .po file.
I want to add a new text of english and convert it into it's respective nepali language.
why I am not being able to add a new english string with its respective string in nepali language.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how gettext translations work. Source strings for translation are extracted from source code. It doesn't make sense to add them manually — they would never be used if they didn't have corresponding source code that uses them. So the way to add strings is to use xgettext or Poedit's update from sources functionality.

(BTW, all this is explained in the gettext manual — I strongly recommend having at least a brief look at it if you’re new to gettext. It makes things much easier.)